# Racket - How to get value from text-field in scheme

Tags: list, parsing, scheme, racket

I have some questions about MIT Scheme language.

I use DrRacket editor and racket langage (#lang racket/gui)

**1) How to get value from text-field ?**

***Answer: (send myText-Field get-value) --->  OK for this***

2) How to lock a text-field

**3) How to convert the text getting from 1) to a "list"**

```
for example if user enter : ------------------------
                            | '(a b a b c a d u)   |
                            ------------------------
how to get this value and convert it into a liste to have the following result: '(a b a b c a d u)
```

**4) How to convert the text getting from 1) to an "atom"**

```
for example if user enter : ------------------------
                            | 'a                   |
                            ------------------------
how to get this value and convert it into an "atom" to have the following result: 'a
```

5) How to include a DrRacket file which contain my process functions (business layer) into gui(presentation layer) procedure file ?

Answer (score 2):

For 3) and 4).

```
> (read (open-input-string "(a b c d e f)"))
'(a b c d e f)
> (read (open-input-string "'(a b c d e f)"))
''(a b c d e f)
> (read (open-input-string "a"))
'a
> (read (open-input-string "'a"))
''a
```

Note: Instead of putting multiple questions into one post, split them.
      The question-and-answer format on this site handles single, focused questions better.

Comment: so, i can write : (read (open-input-string (send myTextField get-value))). Right ??

Comment: Yes. That's the idea.

Comment: but if I realy want that the user enter '(a b c d e f) ---> it's will return ' '(a b c d e f). How to delete one " ' " ?

Comment: '( a b) is short for (quote a b). So remove it with cdr. That is: (cdr (read ...)).