# How do I convert a list written on a text field from lstring to list?

Tags: string, list, user-interface, scheme, racket

I'm not an English native, so if there are any mistakes, please correct me.
I have written a program that takes an arithmetic expression and reduces it. It takes a list and returns a list like this one: `'((a + 2) * b)`.
The user can only use addition and multiplication.

I'm trying to create a GUI that will take the list, reduce it and return the result. But the text field only returns a string value. I want to convert the string value in a list like the precedent example.
If the user writes `(a + (b * 1))`, how do I convert it into a list `(a + (b * 1))`?

Here is what I have done.

```
(define (convert string)
  (map string->symbol          ; convert each substring into a symbol
       (string-split string))) ; split the string by its spaces

; Crée une fenêtre "Simplifier"
(define frame (new frame% [label "Simplifier"]))

; Crée un conteneur "panel"
(define panel (new vertical-panel% [parent frame]))

; Crée un message dans le conteneur "panel)
(define msg (new message%
                 [parent panel]
                 [label "Donnez une expression à simplifier.
N'oubliez pas les parenthèses!"]))

; Crée un champ de texte
(define text-field (new text-field%
                        (label "Expression : ")
                        (parent panel)))

; Crée un message qui affichera le résultat
(define message (new message%
                     (parent panel)
                     (auto-resize #t)
                     (label " ")))

; Faire le bouton "Validez"
(new button% [parent panel]
             [label "Validez"]
             ; Procédure Callback pour un clique sur le bouton "Validez":
             [callback (lambda (button event)
                         (define text (simplifier (convert (send text-field get-value))))
                         (send message set-label (slist->string text)))])

; Affiche la fenêtre
(send frame show #t)
```

Here the result of convert:

```
> (convert "(a + b)")
'(|(a| + |b)|)
```

Can I have a suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Racket - How to get value from text-field in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055591/racket-how-to-get-value-from-text-field-in-scheme)

Comment: It works when I test in the interpreter. `> (read (open-input-string "(a + (b + c))")) :
 '(a + (b + c))``. But on the window, I write the same thing, and it returns this : `symbol→string: contract violation
  expected: symbol?
  Given: '(b + c)`

Comment: I don't think your gui version is using `read`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I didn't keep my promise to update.
Here how I made it work.

```
; Convert a list in a list of string
(define list->slist (lambda (l)
                      (cond
                        ((null? l)       '())
                        ((list? (car l)) (cons (list->slist (car l)) (list->slist (cdr l))))
                        ((Cte? (car l))  (cons (number->string (car l)) (list->slist (cdr l))))
                        (#t              (cons (symbol->string (car l)) (list->slist (cdr l))))
                        )))

; Convert a list of string in string
(define convert (lambda (slst)
                  (cond
                    ((null? slst)       "")
                    ((list? (car slst)) (string-append "(" (convert (car slst)) " " (convert (cdr slst)) ")"))
                    (#t                 (string-append (car slst) " " (convert (cdr slst))))
                    )))
```

It works for me. I can't see any simpler way.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you

```
(define (convert string) (eval (read ( open-input-string (string-append "'" string) ) ) ) )
```

This is the behaviour. You can get each element of the list

```
> (display (convert "((a + 2) * b)" ) ) (display "\n")
((a + 2) * b)
> (display (list-ref (convert "((a + 2) * b)" ) 0 ) ) (display "\n")
(a + 2)
> (display (list-ref (convert "((a + 2) * b)" ) 1 ) ) (display "\n")
*
> (display (list-ref (convert "((a + 2) * b)" ) 2 ) ) (display "\n")
b
>
```

Try it from your interface replacing your button with this code:

```
; Faire le bouton "Validez"
(new button% [parent panel]
             [label "Validez"]
             ; Procédure Callback pour un clique sur le bouton "Validez":
             [callback (lambda (button event)
                         ;(define text (simplifier (convert (send text-field get-value))))
                         ;(send message set-label (slist->string text)))])
                         (display (convert (send text-field get-value) ) )
                         (display "\n")
                         (display (list-ref (convert (send text-field get-value) ) 0 ) )
                         (display "\n")
                         (display (list-ref (convert (send text-field get-value) ) 1 ) )
                         (display "\n")
                         (display (list-ref (convert (send text-field get-value) ) 2 ) )
                         (display "\n")
              )])
```

and writing this expression in your interface's textfield

```
((a + 2) * b)
```

the result should be:

```
((a + 2) * b)
(a + 2)
*
b
```

Hope this helps!