# How to parse string to list in typed racket

Tags: parsing, racket, typed-racket, s-expression

I am working on writing a simple parser in typed Racket, and as part of it, I want to parse string representations of s-expressions to lists as follows:

`"(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))"` => `(list '+ 1 (list '/ 2 (list 'inc 0 )))`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Er, `read`? Plus validation/casting/etc. to make the type checker happy. Simpler to do in regular Racket because of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36055915/9952196 for an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Racket - How to get value from text-field in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055591/racket-how-to-get-value-from-text-field-in-scheme)

Comment: What type signature are you using for these lists, anyways?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure how you exactly expect the conversion result works, but i have to proposals for you.

Supposing this is the current behaviour of your list:

```
> (list-ref (list '+ 1 (list '/ 2 (list 'inc 0 ))) 0 )
+
> (list-ref (list '+ 1 (list '/ 2 (list 'inc 0 ))) 1 )
1
> (list-ref (list '+ 1 (list '/ 2 (list 'inc 0 ))) 2 )
(/ 2 (inc 0))
```

**The first one**

```
(read (open-input-string "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" ) )
```

This will work exactly as your current list (executing in console):

```
> (list-ref (read (open-input-string "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" ) ) 0)
+
> (list-ref (read (open-input-string "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" ) ) 1)
1
> (list-ref (read (open-input-string "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" ) ) 2)
(/ 2 (inc 0))
```

**The second one**

```
(read (open-input-string (string-replace "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" "(" "(list '") ) )
```

This will convert the input string exactly as your desired output, an then convert it into list (executing in console):

```
> (list-ref (read (open-input-string (string-replace "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" "(" "(list '") ) ) 0)
list
> (list-ref (read (open-input-string (string-replace "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" "(" "(list '") ) ) 1)
'+
> (list-ref (read (open-input-string (string-replace "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" "(" "(list '") ) ) 2)
1
> (list-ref (read (open-input-string (string-replace "(+ 1 (/ 2 (inc 0)))" "(" "(list '") ) ) 3)
(list '/ 2 (list 'inc 0))
```

I hope this was helpful for you! Let me know if something gone wrong!